# IoT Edge telemetry does not show up in IoT Central

Tags: azure-iot-edge, telemetry, azure-iot-central

I've created a device template for my IoT Edge in Iot Central.

I'm able to see the modules running on my device through **(Devices-> Group of my device-> My Device -> Modules)** and confirm it connecting to my IoT Edge and running **sudo iotedge list**.

I can also manage it and change the module twin desired properties through  **(Devices-> Group of my device-> My Device -> Manage)** but I cannot see my telemetry data showing up.

In Analysis tab it is also possible to count the ocurrence of those specified fields in telemetry message, capabilities in device template.

Do you guys know what could be happening and what should I do to troubleshoot it?

Thanks in advance!

[Device dashboard view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5fQmg.png)

[Analysis dashboard view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CtlF3.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a mispelling in the code.

Aparently in Analysis tab it was counting the message quantities but not it's intent.

Comment: Please accept your response as answer incase if your issue is resolved